# How to solve for 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined' using Axios and React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, mern

I'm implementing a 'delete' function into my application. Said function deletes the specific 'post._id' after having been clicked. Unfortunately, it is not working.

The function itself works great, it deletes the rows that I click on; the error just shows after deleting the row.

I have this in my React component:

```
<td className="btn-group">
  <button onClick={() => deletePost(post._id)} type="button" className="btn btn-sm">Delete</button>
</td>
```

Said button triggers an Axios request.Here it is request:

```
// Delete post
export const deletePost = (id) => async dispatch => {
  try {

    const res = await axios.delete(`/api/admin/pages/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_PAGE,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Page Removed', 'success'));

  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PAGE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

The function works, there's not problem with it or at least that's what I'm telling myself. What its actually bothering me quite a lot is the error that is shown after triggering the button. The error is this one:
[image: Error shown after button has been triggered]

Do you guys have any idea why is trowing me said error?.

Note: this is my reducer:

```
case DELETE_PAGE:
  return {
    ...state,
    pages: state.pages.filter(page => page._id !== payload),
    loading: false
  };
```

Comment: `console.log(err)` and see what you get as error object. Complain is there is no `response` key on err object

Comment: what is err.response? try to put there only err and console it to check.

Comment: I did the 'console.log(err);' as you guys suggested and then it says:
'TypeError: state.pages.filter is not a function'

Comment: that error sends me to my reducer 'case' which you can see in the question, please, reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.delete("url",reqpayload).then((res)=>{
console.log("response object",res)
console.log("response data",res.data)
//dispatch function, use the res object from the then function
)
.catch((err)=>
console.log("err response",err)
```

this code will help you understand the error